# how to debug Oracle Long Running query execution is taking more than 24 hours

Tags: oracle

```
with ObjectHistory as  ( 
        select temp.OBJECT_KEY, MAX(temp.SOURCE_EVENT_DATE) as MAXSED, temp.USER_NAME, temp.EVENT_DATE FROM  ( 
        SELECT max(OBJECT_KEY) as OBJECT_KEY, USER_NAME, EVENT_DATE, SOURCE_EVENT_DATE  
        FROM V_AAA GROUP BY OBJECT_HISTORY_KEY, USER_NAME, EVENT_DATE, SOURCE_EVENT_DATE ) temp, BBB SKM  
        WHERE SKM.OBJECT_KEY = temp.OBJECT_KEY and SKM.ULT_PARENT_OBJECT_KEY = 2  GROUP BY temp.OBJECT_KEY, temp.SOURCE_EVENT_DATE, temp.USER_NAME, temp.EVENT_DATE  
    ) 
    SELECT H.OBJECT_KEY, H.USER_NAME, H.EVENT_DATE FROM ObjectHistory H ;
```

**Here**

`V_AAA` :*It is a view and*
`BBB`   : *It is 11 Million Records Table*

Execution of this query is taking ages and never finishes.

**Windows Resource Monitor** :

```
Disk I/O : Reads (1 million Bytes/sec) ,
Write (55,000 Bytes/Sec) : 100% Highest Active Time

Physical Memory (16 GB) : 82%  Used

CPU (4 core, 2.24 GHz) : 12% Used
```

I also followed this blog : http://www.orafaq.com/node/854. None of the queries are blocked.

From `dba_objects` table has an entry with `object_name` : `BBB` and Lock Mode : `3`

**Query Plan follows**

```
Plan hash value: 3833081753

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                               | Name               | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                        |                    |  2844 |   166K|       |  1186K  (2)| 03:57:17 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                          |                    |  2844 |   166K|       |  1186K  (2)| 03:57:17 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                             |                    |  2844 |   166K|       |  1186K  (2)| 03:57:17 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | BBB                |  3384 | 33840 |       |   492   (0)| 00:00:06 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | IK_BBB3            |  3593 |       |       |    14   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    VIEW                                 |                    |  4858K|   231M|       |  1185K  (2)| 03:57:11 |
|   6 |     HASH GROUP BY                       |                    |  4858K|   264M|   335M|  1185K  (2)| 03:57:11 |
|   7 |      VIEW                               | V_AAA              |  4858K|   264M|       |  1118K  (2)| 03:43:43 |
|   8 |       UNION-ALL                         |                    |       |       |       |            |          |
|   9 |        NESTED LOOPS                     |                    |     1 |   193 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  10 |         NESTED LOOPS                    |                    |     1 |   153 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  11 |          NESTED LOOPS                   |                    |     1 |   133 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  12 |           NESTED LOOPS                  |                    |     1 |    90 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  13 |            NESTED LOOPS                 |                    |     1 |    78 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  14 |             NESTED LOOPS                |                    |     1 |    57 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  15 |              NESTED LOOPS               |                    |     1 |    49 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|* 16 |               HASH JOIN                 |                    |     1 |    46 |       |   119K  (3)| 00:23:50 |
|  17 |                INDEX FULL SCAN          | PK276_1            |     1 |    13 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL        | AAA                |    79M|  2492M|       |   118K  (2)| 00:23:43 |
|* 19 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK84               |     1 |     3 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |              TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| UOM                |     1 |     8 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |               INDEX UNIQUE SCAN         | PK3                |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |             TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | RU                 |     1 |    21 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |              INDEX UNIQUE SCAN          | PK1                |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | CTL_O_VER          |     1 |    12 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 25 |             INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | PK6                |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID   | CTL_O              |     1 |    43 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 27 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | PK240              |     1 |       |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 28 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | OBJECT_TYPE        |     1 |    20 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 29 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | PK10               |     1 |       |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 30 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                | IX1_BBB            |     1 |    40 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 31 |        HASH JOIN                        |                    |  2100K|   368M|       |   503K  (1)| 01:40:38 |
|  32 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL               | RU                 |   450 |  9450 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 33 |         HASH JOIN                       |                    |  2100K|   326M|       |   503K  (1)| 01:40:38 |
|  34 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL              | UOM                |   691 |  5528 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 35 |          HASH JOIN                      |                    |  2100K|   310M|       |   503K  (1)| 01:40:38 |
|  36 |           INDEX FULL SCAN               | PK84               |    35 |   105 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |           HASH JOIN                     |                    |  2100K|   304M|       |   503K  (1)| 01:40:38 |
|  38 |            INDEX FAST FULL SCAN         | PK11               |  1197 |  4788 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |            HASH JOIN                    |                    |  2936K|   414M|   133M|   503K  (1)| 01:40:37 |
|* 40 |             HASH JOIN                   |                    |  1105K|   121M|    84M|   208K  (1)| 00:41:40 |
|* 41 |              HASH JOIN                  |                    |   770K|    75M|   198M| 88103   (1)| 00:17:38 |
|* 42 |               HASH JOIN                 |                    |  2772K|   166M|       | 50385   (2)| 00:10:05 |
|* 43 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL        | OBJECT_TYPE        |    12 |   240 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  44 |                TABLE ACCESS FULL        | CTL_O              |    20M|   852M|       | 50235   (1)| 00:10:03 |
|  45 |               INDEX FAST FULL SCAN      | IX1_BBB            |  5781K|   220M|       | 13557   (1)| 00:02:43 |
|  46 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL          | CTL_O_VER          |    29M|   341M|       | 81689   (1)| 00:16:21 |
|  47 |             TABLE ACCESS FULL           | AAA                |    79M|  2492M|       |   118K  (2)| 00:23:43 |
|* 48 |        HASH JOIN                        |                    |  2757K|   512M|       |   496K  (2)| 01:39:16 |
|  49 |         INDEX FAST FULL SCAN            | PK11               |  1197 |  4788 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 50 |         HASH JOIN                       |                    |  2757K|   502M|       |   496K  (1)| 01:39:15 |
|* 51 |          TABLE ACCESS FULL              | DIGD               |  2357 | 25927 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 52 |          HASH JOIN                      |                    |  1957K|   336M|       |   496K  (1)| 01:39:15 |
|  53 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL             | RU                 |   450 |  9450 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 54 |           HASH JOIN                     |                    |  1957K|   296M|       |   496K  (1)| 01:39:15 |
|  55 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL            | UOM                |   691 |  5528 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |            HASH JOIN                    |                    |  1957K|   281M|       |   496K  (1)| 01:39:15 |
|  57 |             INDEX FULL SCAN             | PK84               |    35 |   105 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 58 |             HASH JOIN                   |                    |  1957K|   276M|    89M|   496K  (1)| 01:39:15 |
|* 59 |              HASH JOIN                  |                    |   736K|    80M|    56M|   203K  (1)| 00:40:43 |
|* 60 |               HASH JOIN                 |                    |   513K|    50M|   132M| 84815   (1)| 00:16:58 |
|* 61 |                HASH JOIN                |                    |  1848K|   111M|       | 50385   (2)| 00:10:05 |
|* 62 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL       | OBJECT_TYPE        |     8 |   160 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  63 |                 TABLE ACCESS FULL       | CTL_O              |    20M|   852M|       | 50235   (1)| 00:10:03 |
|  64 |                INDEX FAST FULL SCAN     | IX1_BBB            |  5781K|   220M|       | 13557   (1)| 00:02:43 |
|  65 |               TABLE ACCESS FULL         | CTL_O_VER          |    29M|   341M|       | 81689   (1)| 00:16:21 |
|  66 |              TABLE ACCESS FULL          | AAA                |    79M|  2492M|       |   118K  (2)| 00:23:43 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("SKM"."OBJECT_KEY"="TEMP"."OBJECT_KEY")
   4 - access("SKM"."ULT_PARENT_OBJECT_KEY"=2)
  16 - access("W"."EAWORKSPACE_ID"="OB"."CTL_DIAGRAM_ID")
  19 - access("RO"."REPO_OPERATION_ID"="OB"."REPO_OPERATION_ID")
  21 - access("OB"."UOM_ID"="UON"."UOM_ID")
  23 - access("RU"."RU_ID"="UON"."RU_ID")
  25 - access("OB"."CTL_O_VER_ID"="COV"."CTL_O_VER_ID")
  27 - access("COV"."CTL_O_ID"="CO"."CTL_O_ID")
  28 - filter("OT"."NAME"='EADIAGRAM' OR "OT"."NAME"='EAPROJECT' OR "OT"."NAME"='EAWORKSPACE')
  29 - access("OT"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID"="CO"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
  30 - access("SKM"."SOURCE_GUID"="CO"."OBJECT_GUID")
  31 - access("RU"."RU_ID"="UON"."RU_ID")
  33 - access("OB"."UOM_ID"="UON"."UOM_ID")
  35 - access("RO"."REPO_OPERATION_ID"="OB"."REPO_OPERATION_ID")
  37 - access("D"."DIAGRAM_ID"="OB"."CTL_DIAGRAM_ID")
  39 - access("OB"."CTL_O_VER_ID"="COV"."CTL_O_VER_ID")
  40 - access("COV"."CTL_O_ID"="CO"."CTL_O_ID")
  41 - access("SKM"."SOURCE_GUID"="CO"."OBJECT_GUID")
  42 - access("OT"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID"="CO"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
  43 - filter("OT"."NAME"='ATTRIBUTE' OR "OT"."NAME"='CHECK_CONSTRAINT' OR "OT"."NAME"='DB_VIEW' OR 
              "OT"."NAME"='DIAGRAM' OR "OT"."NAME"='ENTITY' OR "OT"."NAME"='ENTITY_DISPLAY' OR "OT"."NAME"='MODEL' OR 
              "OT"."NAME"='RELATIONSHIP' OR "OT"."NAME"='RELATIONSHIP_DISPLAY' OR "OT"."NAME"='SUBMODEL' OR 
              "OT"."NAME"='VIEW_DISPLAY' OR "OT"."NAME"='VIEW_FIELD')
  48 - access("D"."DIAGRAM_ID"="DD"."DIAGRAM_ID")
  50 - access("DD"."ENTERPRISE_DD_ID"="OB"."CTL_DIAGRAM_ID")
  51 - filter("DD"."FLAGS"=0 OR "DD"."FLAGS"=1)
  52 - access("RU"."RU_ID"="UON"."RU_ID")
  54 - access("OB"."UOM_ID"="UON"."UOM_ID")
  56 - access("RO"."REPO_OPERATION_ID"="OB"."REPO_OPERATION_ID")
  58 - access("OB"."CTL_O_VER_ID"="COV"."CTL_O_VER_ID")
  59 - access("COV"."CTL_O_ID"="CO"."CTL_O_ID")
  60 - access("SKM"."SOURCE_GUID"="CO"."OBJECT_GUID")
  61 - access("OT"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID"="CO"."OBJECT_TYPE_ID")
  62 - filter("OT"."NAME"='ATTACHMENT' OR "OT"."NAME"='ATTACHMENT_TYPE' OR "OT"."NAME"='DATA_DICTIONARY' OR 
              "OT"."NAME"='DEFAULT' OR "OT"."NAME"='DOMAIN' OR "OT"."NAME"='REFERENCE_VALUE' OR "OT"."NAME"='RULE' OR 
              "OT"."NAME"='USER_DATATYPE')
```

**View Script : V_AAA**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW "V_AAA" ("AAA_KEY", "OBJECT_KEY", "OPERATION", "EVENT_DATE", "SOURCE_EVENT_DATE", "USER_NAME", "USER_COMMENT", "SYNC_DATE", "SOURCE_GUID", "DIAG_GUID", "OBJECT_TYPE", "SOURCE_SYSTEM") AS 
  SELECT
  OB.Object_History_ID AAA_KEY,
  SKM.OBJECT_KEY OBJECT_KEY,
  RO.Name OPERATION,
  (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(OB.Event_Date, 'second')) EVENT_DATE, -- now it is the GMT time
  OB.Event_Date SOURCE_EVENT_DATE,
  RU.Name USER_NAME,
  RC.String USER_COMMENT,
  OB.Event_Date*1000 SYNC_DATE,
  CO.Object_GUID SOURCE_GUID,
  W.Object_GUID DIAG_GUID,
  OT.Name OBJECT_TYPE,
  'EASTUDIO' as SOURCE_SYSTEM
FROM Object_History OB
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj_Ver COV on OB.ctl_obj_Ver_ID = COV.ctl_obj_Ver_ID
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj CO on COV.ctl_obj_ID = CO.ctl_obj_ID
  INNER JOIN sk_map SKM on SKM.SOURCE_GUID = CO.Object_GUID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Repo_Comment RC on OB.Repo_Comment_ID = RC.Repo_Comment_ID
  INNER JOIN repo_oper RO on RO.repo_oper_ID = OB.repo_oper_ID
  INNER JOIN User_On_Machine UON on OB.User_On_Machine_ID = UON.User_On_Machine_ID 
  INNER JOIN Repo_User RU on RU.Repo_User_ID = UON.Repo_User_ID 
  INNER JOIN EAWorkspace W on W.EAWorkspace_ID = OB.Ctl_Diag_ID 
  INNER JOIN Object_Type OT on OT.Object_Type_ID = CO.Object_Type_ID
WHERE
    OT.Name in ('EAWORKS','EADIAG','EAPROJ')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  OB.Object_History_ID as AAA_KEY,
  SKM.OBJECT_KEY OBJECT_KEY,
  RO.Name as OPERATION,
  (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(OB.Event_Date, 'second')) EVENT_DATE, -- now it is the GMT time
  OB.Event_Date as SOURCE_EVENT_DATE,
  RU.Name as USER_NAME,
  RC.String as USER_COMMENT,
  OB.Event_Date*1000 SYNC_DATE,
  CO.Object_GUID as SOURCE_GUID,
  D.Object_GUID as DIAG_GUID,
  OT.Name as OBJECT_TYPE,
  'ERStudio' as SOURCE_SYSTEM
FROM Object_History OB
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj_Ver COV on OB.ctl_obj_Ver_ID = COV.ctl_obj_Ver_ID
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj CO on COV.ctl_obj_ID = CO.ctl_obj_ID
  INNER JOIN sk_map SKM on SKM.SOURCE_GUID = CO.Object_GUID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Repo_Comment RC on OB.Repo_Comment_ID = RC.Repo_Comment_ID
  INNER JOIN repo_oper RO on RO.repo_oper_ID = OB.repo_oper_ID
  INNER JOIN User_On_Machine UON on OB.User_On_Machine_ID = UON.User_On_Machine_ID
  INNER JOIN Repo_User RU on RU.Repo_User_ID = UON.Repo_User_ID
  INNER JOIN Diag D on D.Diag_ID = OB.Ctl_Diag_ID
  INNER JOIN Object_Type OT on OT.Object_Type_ID = CO.Object_Type_ID
WHERE
  OT.Name in ('DIAG','MODEL','ENTITY','ATTRIBUTE','ENTITY_DISPLAY',
  'RELATIONSHIP','RELATIONSHIP_DISPLAY','SUBMODEL','CHECK_CONSTRAINT',
  'DB_VIEW','VIEW_FIELD','VIEW_DISPLAY')
UNION ALL
SELECT
  OB.Object_History_ID as AAA_KEY,
  SKM.OBJECT_KEY OBJECT_KEY,
  RO.Name as OPERATION,
  (TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00.0' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(OB.Event_Date, 'second')) EVENT_DATE, -- now it is the GMT time
  OB.Event_Date as SOURCE_EVENT_DATE,
  RU.Name as USER_NAME,
  RC.String as USER_COMMENT,
  OB.Event_Date*1000 SYNC_DATE,
  CO.Object_GUID as SOURCE_GUID,
  D.Object_GUID as DIAG_GUID,
  OT.Name as OBJECT_TYPE,
  'ERStudio' as SOURCE_SYSTEM
FROM Object_History OB
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj_Ver COV on OB.ctl_obj_Ver_ID = COV.ctl_obj_Ver_ID
  INNER JOIN ctl_obj CO on COV.ctl_obj_ID = CO.ctl_obj_ID
  INNER JOIN sk_map SKM on SKM.SOURCE_GUID = CO.Object_GUID
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Repo_Comment RC on OB.Repo_Comment_ID = RC.Repo_Comment_ID
  INNER JOIN repo_oper RO on RO.repo_oper_ID = OB.repo_oper_ID
  INNER JOIN User_On_Machine UON on OB.User_On_Machine_ID = UON.User_On_Machine_ID
  INNER JOIN Repo_User RU on RU.Repo_User_ID = UON.Repo_User_ID
  INNER JOIN Diag_DD DD on DD.Enterprise_DD_ID = OB.Ctl_Diag_ID
  INNER JOIN Diag D on D.Diag_ID = DD.Diag_ID
  INNER JOIN Object_Type OT on OT.Object_Type_ID = CO.Object_Type_ID
WHERE
  OT.Name in ('DATA_DIC','DOMAIN', 'REFE_VAL','DEFAULT',
  'RULE','USER_DATATYPE','ATT_TYPE','ATTACH')
  AND DD.Flags in (0,1);
```

Comment: Check out `v$session_longops` to see what the query is doing.

Comment: Show us the execution plan.

Comment: my guess is the query uses a very expensive index, show us the plan

Comment: @Wernfried : Here is the execution paln for this query : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B61Su0IyA04TQWdINUxnUjd2Vkk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit your question and put the execution plan as text instead of a picture in comment.

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit - done

Comment: There is no such thing as a a view table -- a view is just a query that is included in the query that references it. You need to show the definition of that view also.

Comment: @david-aldridge : Agree view is a query. It was typo error, Thanks.  Shared the view details. Please take a look.

Comment: "TABLE ACCESS FULL        | AAA                |    79M|  2492M| "

There's your problem there

Comment: @AndrewBrennan I shouldn't think so -- the query plan estimates that that's only a 23 minute operation.

Comment: @david-aldridge : What could be the problem for query execution in ages(> 24 hours), if the query plan estimates 23 minutes. Disk I/O reaching to high value (Reads (1 million Bytes/sec)).

Also Can you please let me understand, how did you calculate 23 minute from the explain plan.

Comment: @SatishYandagudita The plan shows 79M rows, 2492Mb to be read, at a cost of 118K and estimated time of 00:23:43. That's about 1,400 seconds to read 2.5GB, so about 1.8MB/sec. Check your storage read speed -- it looks like you're running this on a very poorly equipped system, if those estimates are correct.

Comment: YEah but then you're going to hash join part of the result set with: |* 31 |        HASH JOIN                        |                    |  2100K|   368M|       |   503K  (1)| 01:40:38 |
|  32 |         TABLE ACCESS FULL               | RU                 |   450 |  9450 |       |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |

At an estimated cost of 1:40:00. It's all interrelated.